# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: ajax, reactjs

Tengo el siguiente error:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

He buscado en otros foros pero algunos recomiendan que puede ser problema del archivo Json por la sintaxis, Pero ya lo he validado en http://jsonlint.com/ y no presenta ningún problema. .
Estoy usando React, ¿Cuál podría ser el error y cómo podría solucionarlo?

---

Este es mi Archivo Json:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Enrique"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Camilo"
    },
    {
        "name": "Alex"
    },
    {
        "name": "Artemo"
    }
]
```

Estoy usando Fetch dejo el codigo:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    fetch('json/users.json')
        .then(userJson => userJson.json(), e => {
            console.log("Obtención fallida", e);
        })
        .then(userJson => {
            console.log(userJson);
    });
},
```

Comment: Revisa que el recurso `json/users.json` devuelva un json.

Comment: Probaste con  `.then(userJson => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(userJson));
  });` ??

Comment: Tienes un error de sintaxis. Para saber si la petición ha fallado, se usa `.catch(e)` donde `e` es el error que contiene información al respecto.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba usando este fetch

```js
fetch (`json/users.json`, {
      method: 'POST'
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      if (res.success) {
        //mensaje correcto
      }else{
      //mensaje de error
      }
    })
    .catch(function() {
      alert("Can't connect to backend try latter");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Al apuntar a rutas externas http de tu aplicación tienes que especificar el protocolo a utilizar al inicio de la url de fetch.

En tu caso sería

```
// Observa como agrego https al inicio de la url, tambien funciona con http
fetch('https://json/users.json')
        .then(userJson => userJson.json(), e => {
            console.log("Obtención fallida", e);
        })
        .then(userJson => {
            console.log(userJson);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` se usa comunmente para jalar datos de un API con metodos http, así que la llamada a tu api debería comenzar con http, de otra manera recibirás los datos en un formato que no esperas, no olvides de setear tus headers a algo como:

```
fetch (`json/users.json`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
         "Accept": "application/json"
 }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A mí me pasó lo mismo trabajando también con React. Simplemente, mueve tu archivo (o tu carpeta con los archivos dentro) en el directorio "public". En tu caso, el string del path sería:

```
"./json/users.json"
```

Answer (score -1):

De seguro que el error este en el JSON que retorna.

Me sucede el mismo error en este [ejemplo](https://runkit.com/jondotsoy/error-parse-json).

```
// Example: https://runkit.com/jondotsoy/error-parse-json
const myJSON = `
{<

    "hola": 3
}
`


JSON.parse(myJSON)
```